# How to graph columns of a matrix against the rows in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, matrix, plot

so I am having some issues about how to plot this matrix. It's basically a matrix where the 1st column is the number of years and then the row with that column are random variables that have been simulated.

How would I be able to plot a graph where the x axis is the year number (column 1) and then we plot the rows against it? Eg for 1 on the x-axis I will have 5 points for it, 0.33432948, 0.06990206 etc. I will need to look into changing the y-axis limits since there are so many points and I want a spread out graph but I think I can worry about that later.

I have looked into ggplot2 and tidyverse but haven't had any luck finding anything useful so far. Thanks a bunch!

```
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
 [1,]    1 0.33432948 0.06990206 0.05479009 0.03561347 0.09225090
 [2,]    2 0.12517444 0.03190385 0.11468735 0.03905080 0.08880641
 [3,]    3 0.13304605 0.03058939 0.17782558 0.07074068 0.19275310
 [4,]    4 0.10048548 0.03858150 0.22797194 0.06269640 0.20969944
 [5,]    5 0.10934330 0.10028905 0.01210302 0.01143484 0.12816420
 [6,]    6 0.03646873 0.13893758 0.05368435 0.21892630 0.24976405
 [7,]    7 0.08412910 0.11280857 0.04691009 0.25731222 0.03220878
 [8,]    8 0.05843632 0.07054884 0.21108606         NA         NA
 [9,]    9 0.03934863 0.09538574 0.07085261 0.20016386 0.11080113
[10,]   10 0.21394149 0.05896028 0.05786250 0.09090584 0.06395972
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. You can set a data pipeline and then reshape the data to long keeping the first column as reference and spreading the remaining ones. With that format you can desing the plot to see the values across each column. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
mat %>% as.data.frame %>%
  pivot_longer(-V1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(V1),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(color='Column',x='V1')+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
mat <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0.33432948, 0.12517444, 
0.13304605, 0.10048548, 0.1093433, 0.03646873, 0.0841291, 0.05843632, 
0.03934863, 0.21394149, 0.06990206, 0.03190385, 0.03058939, 0.0385815, 
0.10028905, 0.13893758, 0.11280857, 0.07054884, 0.09538574, 0.05896028, 
0.05479009, 0.11468735, 0.17782558, 0.22797194, 0.01210302, 0.05368435, 
0.04691009, 0.21108606, 0.07085261, 0.0578625, 0.03561347, 0.0390508, 
0.07074068, 0.0626964, 0.01143484, 0.2189263, 0.25731222, NA, 
0.20016386, 0.09090584, 0.0922509, 0.08880641, 0.1927531, 0.20969944, 
0.1281642, 0.24976405, 0.03220878, NA, 0.11080113, 0.06395972
), .Dim = c(10L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5", "V6")))
```

Comment: So regarding this approach will I need to set the structure first like you have done after the graph and then run the tidyverse code on that structure? This is exactly the output I would like for my data structure as well! Cheers

Comment: So my code can change the number of rows and the number of data that I have. For example, I could have 10000 rows of data. I was just wondering is it possible to manually just put the structure into another matrix and then automatically generate the lists?

Comment: @NeelPatel If you have 1000 rows that means that first column has from 1 to 1000, right? There would not be issue as the plot will be designed. Only the x axis scale can be affected, in that case you could consider removing the `factor()` from `x` in `ggplot()`.

Comment: So with the whole code I have a function where I input parameters and then the matrix is generated from that. So would it be possible to instead of manually structuring the data like you have with mat <- structure(c(1....) could I just replace it instead with 

mat <- structure(c(matrix I have generated in the function))?

The only issue I'm getting my head around is automatically generate the plot according to how many rows are input into the matrix generating function. Would a full copy of my code help you understand my issue? Thanks!

Comment: @NeelPatel The structure is only the data shared for reproducible example. In your real case you must have a matrix defined with n rows and p cols. Just replace the `mat` by the name of your matrix and the code will work!

Comment: Would you be able to help me through what %>% is? I have also tried implementing your code into the function but when I want to plot my data I am not getting an actual output for the graph in the plot area?

Comment: @Nhyi Yeah, it is an operator that means imply, so when you use as `x %>% sum` it means take `x` then sum, it is like a connector.